# jQuery deferred AJAX calls: possible scope issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I'm making multiple AJAX requests inside a loop. Here's my code for that:

```
// set defaults
var app_id = 'xxx';
var secret = 'yyy';
var auth_token = 'zzz';

// list of items to call in the API
var insights_to_check = ['application_permission_views_top_unique', 'application_installation_adds_unique', 'application_installation_removes_unique'];
var json_responses = {};

var ajax_calls = [];

// construct the API url
for (var i in insights_to_check) {
    var insight = insights_to_check[i];
    var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + app_id + '/insights/' + insight + '?' + auth_token;
    ajax_calls.push(get_json(url, insight));
}

// when all ajax requests are done, call the process function
$.when.apply($, ajax_calls).done(function(){
    process_json(json_responses);
});

// collect responses to the ajax request in a global object
function get_json(url, insight) {
    $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
        json_responses[insight] = json;
    });
}

// show the global object
function process_json(all_json) {
    console.log(all_json);
}
```

The code has a weird problem: the first time it runs, I can see the AJAX requests firing and returning, but when `process_json()` gets called, it logs `undefined`. If I manually invoke it a second time, it returns the json as expected.

It seems that my deferred callback is firing before the AJAX requests are complete, or at least. before they've been able to assign their response to the global `json_responses` object. Can anyone see anything glaringly obvious here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why it logs `undefined` ([it does not for me](http://jsfiddle.net/VT2Uk/) if I omit the Ajax calls) but one problem with your code is that the `.done()` callback is executed **immediately** as `ajax_calls` is an **empty** array.

You have to return the return value of `$.getJSON` from `get_json`:

```
function get_json(url, insight) {
    return $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
        json_responses[insight] = json;
    });
}
```

That might solve the issue.

Comment: That did indeed work, it didn't occur to me that without a return value it wouldn't add anything to the array. Thank you!